# Modal disappearing in wrong place after animation is finished

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-modal

I’m having a problem with a modal in react native. Whenever I close the modal, it animates down to this point, then just disappears. How can I fix this and make it happen under the tab control like it’s supposed to?

[image]

Comment: can you add a code example please?

Comment: @İlker, yes - sorry was posting this from phone. Will upload code shortly.